# How to block dataiku dataset from formatting date values?

Tags: dataiku

I've some date values which get automatically format when I pass that through dataiku dataset. I don't want to format those dates. I just want them in the same format in which they are before formatting.

**Before formatting**

[image]

**After formatting**

[image]

---- UPDATE ----

I've fixed this by setting the datatype of each column in dataframe using `astype()` methode.

Example:

```
bucketOutput_df = bucketOutput_df.astype({"bucketStatusDate": str, "bucketSpudDate": str})
```

Comment: How you are loading the data into the Dataiku platform? Is it a file upload or a database connection?

Comment: @Gaur I've already fixed this. Updated my answer in the post itself. I was reading data from one EXCEL Sheet & putting those in Dataiku dataset. Thanks for your reply though.